# Can I hide my 15-day employment in the next background check? I have showed it in my current BG check

Tags: india, background-check, employment-gaps

I’ve left my first company. And had to join another since I didn’t have other offers.

Now that I’ve another offer, I’m planning to join this other company and I’ve been open with them regarding my new employment. I mentioned the same in my background check form.

My question is, in future when I join a new company, should i mention this 15 day employment? And will they find it out since I’ve already mentioned in my current background check?

Comment: "And had to join another" Correction: you chose to join another.

Comment: Haha @PhilipKendall if you're laid off, and no offers, then you don't have any other choice.

Comment: You wrote "**I’ve left my first company**". That is why @PhilipKendall thinks that you had a choice to either join another company or to stay with your old company... :-)

Comment: Ah, got it. Just a matter of choice of words haha

Comment: Just make sure to get your relieving letter from your employer so that people won't think you're (illegally) working two jobs at the same time.

Comment: This post may need to add the sector. Some retail stores have a continuous revolving door of hires with hires only lasting a month being common.

Answer (score 5):

Unless there's a specific reason to hide it that you haven't mentioned I don't see any reason to do so. Sounds like was a placeholder job to get you out of unemployment and now that you have a real opportunity you're moving on, albeit quickly. I doubt any future company will see this as problematic job hopping or lack of commitment, which I assume is what you are worried about.

You can make your question better by adding a country tag, and by giving more detail about what you are worried about by including/excluding this time period in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

This is for India. The only reason I don't want to put is because:-
1. it's just 15 days, doesn't add any value to my employment or career.
2. Additionally, I had this one offer, that I joined. But after getting another offer, I'm leaving it, which questions my trustworthiness towards my future employer.

In reality, I was already interviewing elsewhere but the offers were not confirmed yet. So I had to join this one company.

Comment: My additional question would've been. Do these BG verification companies only cross-verify the info that I provide? Or do they go the extra mile to find out all the info not mentioned by me. If it's the former case, then I don't think skipping would lead to any issues.

Comment: @Aseem okay I understand. My answer stands in terms of no company being too worried about the trustworthiness aspect in this case, but I am not in India so I'm not 100% confident in that. The answer to actual question you have, about these companies' process of verification, will probably be easier found on more specific forums or resources. I certainly don't know. Good luck!